# dynamically checking existing cd rom letter and change it to Z in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
Set-WmiInstance -InputObject ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'd:'" ) -Arguments @{DriveLetter='Z:'}
```

This script will check for cd rom letter and change it to Z .. but only if cd rom letter is D.
how abt dynamically checking existing cd rom letter

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Win32_CDROMDrive` WmiObject which you can use to determine the existing CDROM drive letter:

```
$letter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive | select -ExpandProperty Drive
Set-WmiInstance -InputObject ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = '$letter'" ) -Arguments @{DriveLetter='Z:'}
```